# Casting error when converting double to long

Tags: java

I've run into a strange problem that I'm not understanding. I am working on a Java program that uses the Steam API to get Dota 2 statistics.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_REQUESTS; i++) {
    competitiveMatches.addAll(getByStartTime(startTime));
    System.out.println("Time: " + competitiveMatches.get(competitiveMatches.size() - 1).getStartTime());
    startTime = competitiveMatches.get(competitiveMatches.size() - 1).getStartTime();
}
```

I am getting an error on the `System.out.println(...)` line saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

which to me is not making any sense, I am requesting the last match in my List, and accessing its `start_time` variable which is the method below. It works by looking through the JSON Map and getting the value at the position.

```
@Override
public long getStartTime() {
    return (Long) jsonMap.get(KEY_START_TIME);
}
```

The full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at de.inkvine.dota2stats.domain.impl.MatchOverviewImpl.getStartTime(MatchOverviewImpl.java:48)
at Silicon.main(Silicon.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Where

- `MatchOverviewImpl.java:48` is the return of the `getStartMethod()`
- `Silicon.java:34` is the `System.out.println()` line

An example of a request, the `match_id`, `match_seq_num`, and `start_time` are all stored as doubles e.g. `1.929962146E9`:

```
{  
    "match_id":1929981128,
    "match_seq_num":1705354677,
    "start_time":1447289804,
    "lobby_type":8,
    "radiant_team_id":0,
    "dire_team_id":0,
    "players":[  
        {  
            "account_id":82228820,
            "player_slot":0,
            "hero_id":19
        },
        {  
            "account_id":4294967295,
            "player_slot":128,
            "hero_id":14
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, which method is the exception coming from?

Comment: @Whymarrh I've included the full stack trace.

Comment: @DaveNewton it seems like the JSON is getting back the values in the format: "1.447288188E9" for all values

Comment: Changing all variables from longs to doubles seems to fix the problem, I don't understand why there's an error in conversion or why one would occur during a console output.

Comment: So, they're obviously Doubles. There's an error because you're casting in the method called by the print statement. It says that explicitly in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a `Double` to a `long` via casting, which is not possible. You can convert the `Double` to its `long` counterpart by calling [`longValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longValue--):

```
@Override
public long getStartTime() {
    return jsonMap.get(KEY_START_TIME).longValue();
}
```

This is because in JSON, like JavaScript, [all numbers are floating point numbers](http://www.json.org) (well, [the spec doesn't make any distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)), so it is likely that the JSON library you are using returns you `Double` objects regardless of whether or not the number has a fractional part.

Comment: You might be able to unbox the double and then cast it to a long, but I'd need to double-check that (no pun intended).

Comment: Maps apparently do not have a method that gets their long values.

Comment: @MattBrzezinski I don't understand, the call to `.longValue()` should be to the `Double` that is returned from the `get` call

Comment: @MattBrzezinski Maps of Longs do, but that isn't what you have.

Comment: I've just figured out my mistake, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`Double, Long, Float, Integer, Long, Short` are subclasses of [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), they are not primitives. You cannot cast between them!

Java uses autoboxing only between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes, but unfortunately it doesn't between Objects and primitives of different Number types eg `long to Integer`. To help you on casting between different Number types, each Number object is equipped with `byteValue(),doubleValue(),floatValue(),intValue(),longValue(),shortValue()` methods. So, you can actually call:

```
jsonMap.get(KEY_START_TIME).longValue();
```

or you could even use double-casting, taking advantage of autoboxing

```
(long)(double)jsonMap.get(KEY_START_TIME);
```